# R: list$i variable instead of i in for(i in 1:10)

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to replace the `i` in `for(i in 1:10) { x*i }` with a variable in a list such as `counter$i`

I have some `for` loops in my code, and some need to have different counting variables because I have a loop in a loop, which results in me creating a bunch of variables.

Instead of finding a different way of doing the loops such as a version of apply, I have decided to simply "hide" all the counter variables in a list containing each counter variable such as: `counter$i` for the first variable and `counter$j` as the second etc.

However for loops don't seem to accept `$` or `[[]]` in the counter variables.
Is there any way I can achieve this?

tldr:
I want to replace `for(i in 1:10)` with `for(counter$i in 1:10)` or equivalent

Comment: Could you include sample full code and expected output? Also include some sample data. While the post is detailed, code and expected output always help understand more what is being done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible.  I still question the wisdom of doing it. (in fact, **don't do it**, see below) It will take a lot to convince me that managing loops like this is ever the "best" solution.

the documentation for `for` describes the for loop with usage `for(var in seq) expr`.

`var` is "A syntactical name for a variable".  `counter$i` is not a syntactical name, you can enclose it in backticks to make it syntactical.

```
counter <- list(i = 1)
for (`counter$i` in 1:10){
  print(counter$i)
  counter$i <- counter$i + 1
}
```

The obvious downside is that you need to manually increment `counter$i` (or any other counters).

### Alternative

Is it possible to set up a data frame with all of the conditions you will encounter in the loop?  Through some combination of `expand.grid` or `split`?

Generally, when I encounter a situation that could lead to nested looping, I will find some way to split my data so that each list is an element to be acted on independently.  Then I only need to operate on one counter in a loop.

### ADDITIONS

On further contemplation, I think I have to admit that this doesn't actually "work". It only works in the sense that it obfuscates the iterator out of the loop and let's the user manager their own internal iterator.

Notice below that when printing `counter$i` inside the loop, but without manually incrementing it, it never changes.  But after we leave the loop, if I get the object `get("counter$i")`, I get 10, the last value of the loop's internal iterator.

```
counter <- list(i = 1)
for (`counter$i` in 1:10){
  # always prints 1
  print(counter$i)
}



`counter$i`
> 10 
get("counter$i")
> 10
```

In essence, what I've done here is impose a `for` loop while sacrificing all of the benefits of `for` loop control.  It is error prone and difficult to debug.  Worse, R already has a control for doing exactly this kind of thing. It's called `repeat`.

I think `repeat` would be the correct way to approach what is needed here. As in

```
counter <- list(i = 1)
repeat {
  print(counter$i)
  counter$i <- counter$i + 1
  if (counter$i == 10) break;
}

counter$i
```

Comment: I'm so surprised this works. Given that if you did `\`counter$i\` <- 50` outside the loop, it would create a different variable rather than updating `counter` (a variable with a very weird name). So somehow the `for` iterator isn't treating that as a variable name, but as an expression? Is there a better way to think about what's going on here?

Comment: @MrFlick, I was surprised, too.  But on second thought, it isn't actually working.  See my revision. @Allan should consider using `repeat` instead.

Comment: Ah yes. Somehow I completely missed the fact that you were manually incrementing the counter in the original code sample. Now this all makes sense.